# php array problem

Tags: php

I have a doubt in php regarding array. I have

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fieldset_name] => Personal Details
            [field_name] => applicant_name
            [field_label] => Your Name
            [field_type] => text
            [css_classes] => required
            [minlength] => 4
            [maxlength] => 10
            [default_value] => 
            [help_text] => 
        )
```

Now I want the output will be like a html form.  In that the field will be like this:

```
<label for="applicant_name">Your Name</label><input type="text" maxlength="10" minlength="4" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Michiel Pater's answer:

```
<?php
foreach($array as $element)
{
    echo '<label for="' . $element['field_name'] . '"></label>' . $element['field_label'] . '<input name="' . $element['field_name'] . '" type="' . $element['field_type'] . '" maxlength="' . $element['maxlength'] . '" minlength="' . $element['minlength'] . '" class="' . $element['css_classes'] . '" /><br/>', "\n";
}
```

It looks like you have an array of elements. Meaning that you could have 1 or 99 (or more) elements. Placing the code within a foreach loop means that each of them will be echoed.

Comment: I'd use the for keyword instead of foreach because 'foreach' is a little bit slower than 'for'

Comment: @Jean-Philippe Leclerc: Could you provide some evidence for that statement please?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the following:

```
<?php
$html = '';
foreach($array as $e){
    $html.= "<label for='{$e['field_name']}'>{$e['field_label']}</label>";
    $html.= "<input type='{$e['field_type']}' ".
        "maxlength='{$e['maxlength']}' minlength='{$e['minlength']}' ".
        "class='{$e['css_classes']}' value='{$e['default_value']}' ".
        "title='{$e['help_text']}' />";
}
echo $html;
?>
```

Basiclly just loop through the array, and print out the elements in the right spots.

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = count($field);
$finalString = "";

for($i = 0; $i < $count ; $i ++)
{
    $finalString .= '<label for="' . $fields[$i]['field_name'] . '"></label>' . $fields[$i]['field_label'] . '<input name="' . $fields[$i]['field_name'] . '" type="' . $fields[$i]['field_type'] . '" maxlength="' . $fields[$i]['maxlength'] . '" minlength="' . $fields[$i]['minlength'] . '" class="' . $fields[$i]['css_classes'] . '" />';
}

echo $finalString;
```